# Finding a basis. Technical issue.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was asked to find a basis for the image of linear transformation.
One easy way to do it is applying the linear map on $e_1,...e_n$, the standard basis.

What do you do when $T(e_j) = 0$? Am I suppose to just omit it? what is the explanation for this kind of action? Thanks.

Comment: If $T(e_j) \in \operatorname{sp}\{T e_1,...,T e_{j-1} \}$, then you can omit it. You are looking for a linearly independent spanning set of the space $\{Tx\}_{x \in V}$. In particular, if $Te_j = 0$, it is not 'contributing' anything new to the span.

Comment: In general the linear transformation may not have full rank. In that case you may either find vectors like the one you mentioned (which are mapped to 0) or the image of the basis is not linearly independent. You need to create a basis out of the image of the $e_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your approach is "Collect all $T(e_j)$s and find a basis of their span", you can just omit these cases - the zero vector will be spanned by any basis.

The question what's happening there is probably best answered by the [rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem):

If $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $W$, then the dimensions of the image of $T$, $\mathrm{im}\, T$ and of the kernel (or null space) of $T$ $\mathrm{ker}\, T$ fulfill the following:
$$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{im} (T)) + \mathrm{dim} (\mathrm{ker} (T)) = \mathrm{dim} (V).$$

Which losely translates to "all vectors which do not contribute to the range will end up in the kernel."

There are other methods which might or might not be a better approach: If $T$ is represented by a matrix (w.r.t. bases in $V$ and $W$; in the easiest case the canonical bases), then the range (of cooridinate vectors w.r.t. the basis in $W$) of $T$ is exactly the span of the columns of the representing matrix.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks!